# Can a custom .net application be written for MC55

Tags: .net

Is it possible to write a custom application that supports the .net framework for a Motorola MC55 mobile device. If so what version of the framework should be used?  This device is attached to a PC via a USB cable and is uses as a bar code scanner. The device has MS Office Mobile 2010 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from some [manufacturer](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/mobile-computers/handheld/mc55a0.html)'s site:

> The most advanced mobile operating system for the enterprise
>   Microsoft's Windows 6.5 Mobile Edition increases interoperability with
>   existing enterprise infrastructure; enhances security features;
>   provides a more flexible development platform; improves mobile
>   messaging collaboration.

Thus, you can develop apps using [Compact Framework 3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f44bbwa1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).